# Searching a field inside a leaf in a mongo collection with regex

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following mongo collection with records as seen in the json example record below which represents **one** record. My goal is for example to search for the word "CONST" and find records where the "FullName" field **inside the "Aliases" subtree** contains this word. Taking the record shown as example, it should hit because the leaves 533-1 and 533-2 inside the "Aliases" tree contain the string "CONST" on their respective "FullName" fields. If the Aliases tree contained only the 533-3 leaf inside tree for example, it wouldn't hit.

I use C# and the MongoDb.Driver package and to search with Regex for normal fields - e.g. for "Key" on this collection shown I use "Builders.Filter.And(filter, Builders.Filter.Regex("Key", new BsonRegularExpression("")))" pattern to add a condition. But for these fields inside the "Aliases" subtree I don't know how to add a condition. What would be the simplest way to make a search on this field?

Please note that under "Aliases" each leaf has a different name (533-1, 533-2 etc). Each name of each leaf is unique in every record in the entire collection.
Record example:

```
{
"_id" : "128c5c57-ae95-4a08-9fb8-d6eade663908",
"_t" : "Company",
"ActiveFrom" : "20190813154343",
"ActiveTo" : "30001001000001",
"GroupId" : "38547478-88ef-4caf-a6ce-1a9e6a85a59b",
"Key" : "533",
"FullName" : "RED BRIGADES",
"Countries" : [ 
    "ITALY"
],
"MoreInfo" : null,
"RecordDetail" : "<RecordDetail></RecordDetail>",
"Aliases" : {
    "533-1" : {
        "Key" : "533-1",
        "FullName" : "BRIGADAS ROJAS PARA LA CONSTRUCCIÓN DEL PARTIDO COMUNISTA COMBATIENTE",
        "OriginalKey" : "533"
    },
    "533-2" : {
        "Key" : "533-2",
        "FullName" : "BRIGADES ROUGES POUR LA CONSTRUCTION DU PARTI COMMUNISTE COMBATTANT",
        "OriginalKey" : "533"
    },
    "533-3" : {
        "Key" : "533-3",
        "FullName" : "BRIGATE ROSSE",
        "OriginalKey" : "533"
    },
    "533-4" : {
        "Key" : "533-4",
        "FullName" : "BRIGATE ROSSE PER LA COSTRUZIONE DEL PARTITO COMUNISTA COMBATTENTE",
        "OriginalKey" : "533"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: it would help to remove that image and add a sample json document to your question so that people can simply copy/paste to come up with an answer for you.

Comment: @RyanGunner done thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might run slower than [Ryan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60304542/7177029) query, but this is readable for you to grok it and you to optimize it.

```
db.Companies.aggregate([
    // Add temporary field deconstructed_aliases to every document of collection
    {
        $addFields: {
            deconstructed_aliases: {
                $objectToArray: "$Aliases"
            }
        }
    },
    // Unwind this newly created temporary field deconstructed_aliases
    {
        $unwind: "$deconstructed_aliases"
    },
    // Match on fullName now
    {
        $match: {
            "deconstructed_aliases.v.FullName": {
                $regex: new RegExp('CONST', 'i')
            }
        }
    },
    // Project needed fields
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            key: "$deconstructed_aliases.v.Key",
            fullName: "$deconstructed_aliases.v.FullName"
        }
    }
]);
```

---

The C# driver does not seem to have a [addField](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) helper method in the aggregate fluent interface.

Also there's no direct support for [objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) operator needed to normalize the object, hence creating magic strings as a workaround.

Here's a corresponding C# program -

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");
            IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase("test");
            IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Companies");

            string searchTerm = "CONST";
            string searchResult = FetchKeysBySearchTerm(collection, searchTerm).Result.ToJson();
            Console.WriteLine(searchResult);
        }

        public async static Task<List<BsonDocument>> FetchKeysBySearchTerm(IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection, string searchTerm)
        {
            string addFieldStage = @"{ $addFields: { deconstructed_aliases: { $objectToArray: ""$Aliases"" } } }";
            string unwindStage = @"{ $unwind: ""$deconstructed_aliases"" }";
            string projectStage = @"{ $project: { _id: 0, key: ""$deconstructed_aliases.v.Key"", fullName: ""$deconstructed_aliases.v.FullName"" } }";

            var aggregate = collection.Aggregate()
                                      .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(addFieldStage)
                                      .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(unwindStage)
                                      .Match(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Regex("deconstructed_aliases.v.FullName", new BsonRegularExpression(searchTerm, "i")))
                                      .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(projectStage);


            List<BsonDocument> searchResults = await aggregate.ToListAsync();
            return searchResults;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the sample response -

```
[{ "key" : "533-1", "fullName" : "BRIGADAS ROJAS PARA LA CONSTRUCCIÓN DEL PARTIDO COMUNISTA COMBATIENTE" }, { "key" : "533-2", "fullName" : "BRIGADES ROUGES POUR LA CONSTRUCTION DU PARTI COMMUNISTE COMBATTANT" }]
```

Answer (score 1):

the following aggregation pipeline will get you the results you want. i don't think it would be worth it to try to build this pipeline in c# as there's no builder for `objectToArray` which is needed in your case. if your alias leafs were array items, then we could build a pipeline using the driver's builders. maybe someone else has a better approach. let's see...

```java
db.companies.aggregate([
{
  $match: {
    $expr: {
      $gt: [
        {
          $size: {
            $filter: {
              input: {
                $objectToArray: "$Aliases"
              },
              as: "alias",
              cond: {
                $regexMatch: {
                  input: "$$alias.v.FullName",
                  regex: /CONST/
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        0
      ]
    }
  }
}
])
```

Comment: Hi Ryan thanks for the input. I did try to run this on the collection but got this strange error: (I'm using Robo3T and used a line query db.getCollection('Companies').aggregate.... just like you posted it). Result was like this -> "Failed to execute script.

Error:
Assert: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $expr",
 "code" : 2,
 "codeName" : "BadValue"
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:370:5

Comment: it should work. see here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/25Lcpt8jEyR what is your mongodb server version? it could be a problem with Robo3T. try running the query in the mongo shell.